# How do I update bash on RHEL5 servers with expired contracts?

Tags: bash, redhat, yum, rhel5

I have two servers with expired contracts that are both vulnerable to shellshock.  I am in the process of migrating both to new servers with RHEL6 or greater depending when I get this done.  That being said, running yum fails due to no contract which for such a high level bug, is really shameful of Red Hat.

Nevertheless, how do I get the rpm so I can manually upgrade on both servers?

They are: `Linux intranet 2.6.18-238.12.1.el5PAE #1 SMP Sat May 7 20:37:06 EDT 2011 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux`

Thank you very much!

Comment: You may be able to do a conversion to CentOS, or grab the single CentOS package for bash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to download [bash-3.2-33.el5_11.4.i386](http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/4/idpl/27321150/dir/scientific_linux_5/com/bash-3.2-33.el5_11.4.i386.rpm.html) (or find it at any other alternative location) follow by:

```
yum remove bash
yum localinstall bash
```

Comment: I just did a `rpm -U bash-3.2-33.el5_11.4.i386.rpm` since `yum` itself tried to go onto rhnplugin and that fails.